# I want Raspbian and Retropie; how do I get both?

Tags: retropie

How do I install Retropie on a Raspberry Pi that already has Raspbian installed?

At the very worst I can use BerryBoot if I need another OS.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can just run the [RetroPie setup script](https://retropie.org.uk/docs/Manual-Installation/) and it will install all the dependencies for you.

Or can use berryboot to have a completely separate partition on your SD card.

Or you can just get another SD card and dedicate it to RetroPie.

Answer (score 1):

install rasbian first then log on the desktop using startx and then install retro pi via the desktop consol using this method http://blog.petrockblock.com/2012/07/22/retropie-setup-an-initialization-script-for-retroarch-on-the-raspberry-pi/.

Comment: This Is a link only answer.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the RetroPie setup script. I tried berry boot but had problems accessing the necessary files to modify the config and copy over roms. It also seemed a little slow, but that might have just been me.

Although it can take a while for the setup script to completely run, I'd suggest going that route.

Comment: As you may wonder about the downvotes, I'd like to point out that on this Q&A site you're expected to focus on the original question, not tell your story (even if it's related or even similar). Avoid telling about **your** issues in an answer, avoid asking questions in an answer and stick to the "do X and you'll get Y" format, then it'll be fine. Oh, and sorry about a cold welcome you got, this site isn't like that all the time.