# How to install RetroPie using/alongside NOOBS?

Tags: raspbian, raspbmc, noobs, retropie

Absolute beginner/noob here. I wanted to know if there's a simple way to install NOOBS (Raspbian + RaspBMC, to be specific) and RetroPie on the same SD Card without going through a lot of hoops. More specifically, I wanted to know if I can install RetroPie by somehow using NOOBS itself.

Additional details: I use a Mac Mini; don't have fully-working Windows machine right now. My old SD Card was giving me issues, so I'm planning to use a 32GB Class 10 SDHC Card.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want Raspbian and Retropie; how do I get both?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14824/i-want-raspbian-and-retropie-how-do-i-get-both)

Answer (score 2):

You possibly want to look for something like UltraSlim, where you initially boot into the emulators, and then go to Raspbian, etc from within there.

> You boot into EmulationStation. From there you can choose what you want to do. Media? Load up XBMC or use omxplayer. Want to switch to something else? Just quit out of it and you are thrown back into EmulationStation. Want to surf the web? Load up LXDE. Logout and you are thrown back into EmulationStation. Q3A? Get your frag on. Exit, that and go retro. It's all very seemless for the most part.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=59590
(includes SD Image)

and the UltraSlim Guide here

http://everyday-tech.com/the-complete-guide-to-the-ultraslim-raspberry-pi-image/

Answer (score 1):

using a mac you could copy the whole sd card and paste it into a blank folder. Then click os and delete raspbian (or what you are using) then paste retro pi folder. Go on pi and launch recovery mode and install retro pi.