# RetroPie along with NOOBs

Tags: pi-2, noobs, retropie

Does anyone know how to add RetroPie OS to an already installed NOOBS SD card in Raspberry Pi 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want Raspbian and Retropie; how do I get both?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14824/i-want-raspbian-and-retropie-how-do-i-get-both)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install RetroPie using/alongside NOOBS?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19370/how-to-install-retropie-using-alongside-noobs)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it:

- You can install RetroPie on Raspbian with [this tutorial](https://github.com/retropie/retropie-setup/wiki/manual-installation);
- You can buy another SD card dedicated to RetroPie.

Comment: I guess the first part will not allow me to use Raspbian along with RetroPie.

Comment: Yes, you have Raspian and Retropie

Answer (score 0):

Make this clear for me: You would like to still have NOOBS with RetroPie or just RetroPie?

The first time around i followed [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Installing-RetroPieEmulationStation-onto-Raspberry/step3/Finally-Installing-RetroPieEmulationStation/) tutorial, which guides you all along just installing it. When I got my Pi, I just installed RetroPie on the empty NOOBS (By that I mean NOOBS existing, i just not use it). But you can find the RetroPie disc image on the RetroPie website if you would just like to rewrite the card solely alone just having RetroPie.

[Here](https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/releases/download/4.1/retropie-4.1-rpi2_rpi3.img.gz) is the direct download (If you click it it starts downloading) of the RetroPie image you can use to rewrite the card.

I hope this helps, and I am always open to help you out if you are confused

Comment: That's right I need RetriPie along with NOOBS, that is I want Raspbean as well as RetroPie to work on the same card.
The problem is I need RetroPie for the kids in the house and NOOBs basically for other members for use of KODI and Raspbian for file transfer.