# Retropie installation from the raspberry pi 3 model B

Tags: raspbian, retropie

I want to install Retropie, (that's why I bought the pi) but lost the SD/MicroSD adaptor, so I would like to know if there is a way for me to install retropie using only the pi. thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want Raspbian and Retropie; how do I get both?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14824/i-want-raspbian-and-retropie-how-do-i-get-both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible if Raspbian is installed on your MicroSD card.

```
sudo apt-get install git lsb-release
cd
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup.git
cd RetroPie-Setup
chmod +x retropie_setup.sh
sudo ./retropie_setup.sh
```

[Like this tutorial](https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/wiki/Manual-Installation)

But if you have nothing on your MicroSD card you have to buy a new MicroSD card adapter.

Comment: There is NOOBS running raspbian on my microsd card, but when i get to <chmod +x retropie_setup.sh
sudo ./retropie_setup.sh> it says <Sorry - Raspbian/Debian Stretch (and newer) is not yet supported on the RPI

Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description: Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.1 (stretch)
Release: 9.1
Codename: stretch>  what now?

Comment: Try `sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences` and add following lines:
`Package: *`
`Pin: release a=oldstable`
`Pin-Priority: 1001`